# embeding youtube into async auto updating news feed

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am using a simple AJAX script set to execute every 5 seconds to display all the news feeds from a sql table. everything is working fine but when I want to embed a youtube video into an article it reloads itself every 5 seconds.

is there a way to get around that ?

Here is my script... 'updatedStories.php' basically pulls all the data from my feed table and echoes it .

```
<script>
//get AJAX xmlhttp
function getAJAX(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
//ajax example
function updateStories(){
    var xmlhttp = getAJAX();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("stories").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","updatedStories.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
}
updateStories();
setInterval("updateStories()",5000);
</script>
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing. Could you please post the code you are using?

Comment: **Never** pass a string to `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. Doing so is as bad as using `eval()` and it results in unreadable and possibly insecure code as soon as you use variables since you need to insert them into the string instead of passing the actual variable. The proper solution is `setInterval(function() { /* your code *) }, msecs);`. The same applies to `setTimeout()`. If you just want to call a single function without any arguments, you can also pass the function name directly: `setInterval(someFunction, msecs);` (note that there are **no** `()` behind the function name)

Comment: understood , but that doesn't help with my embeding problem..

Answer (score 1):

You are completely replacing the stories with the new content from the database. This means you are creating new YouTube embeds every time - thus the reload problem. You'll need to change how your page works. Instead of getting all the current stores every five seconds, consider only getting stories that are new/changed since the last update. Unfortunately, it's a significantly more involved solution than your current code.

Comment: I figured as such.. I change my codes but i still have some issues..
I load the posts initially without ajax. each post has a timestamp and they are ordered by it.i store in a session the latest post's timestamp than AJAX runs a script every 5 seconds that runs a query of all the post that are newer than the last timestamp..

but my problem is that i don't know how to compare timestamps in a query.. i can't just write if ($time1>$time2) ,

Comment: I have figured out how to deal with the time and AJAX now appends only newer posts. but in the wrong order :\ it goes like "new newer old old old" instead of "newer new old old old" and if I change the order it ruins my script

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working !
I am using jQuery to prepend the new post so now they come in order.

here are my codes : 
javaScript

```
//get AJAX xmlhttp
function getAJAX(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

setInterval(function (){
    var xmlhttp = getAJAX();

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            //document.getElementById("stories").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText + document.getElementById("stories").innerHTML;
            jQuery("#main_section div#stories").prepend(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","updatedStories.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send();
},5000);
```

than the Script to add new posts :

```
        function update(){
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM stories WHERE time > \''.$_SESSION['last_time'].'\' ORDER BY time DESC ';
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            $first = true;
            while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            $time = $rows['time'];
                if ($first) {
                    $_SESSION['last_time']=$time;
                        $first = false;     
                }
                $title = $rows['title'];
                $user_id =$rows['user_id'];
                $content = $rows['content'];
                display($title,$time,$user_id,$content);
                $_SESSION['last_time']=$time;
            }

        }
```